Quand faut-il faire suivre « arriver » de « jusqu'à » ?
Je suis tombé sur cette phrase dans un livre:

Dehors, la pluie avait enfin cessé, et je restai sur le seuil à les regarder contourner les flaques pour arriver jusqu'à la voiture.

Je me suis rendu compte que je ne sais pas quand utiliser arriver jusqu'à à la place d'arriver à.
Quelle est la différence ici entre « Je suis arrivé à Paris » et « Elle est arrivée jusqu'à la voiture » ?

Your italicization is OK: the emphasis does not include the preceding d'.

Il n'y a pas de différence fondamentale.
Disons que jusqu'à peut sous-entendre une certaine difficulté à atteindre la destination, que ce n'était pas an easy feat, ou qu'il y a plusieurs objectifs possibles et qu'on atteint celui-là. (@Frank)

Enfin, en continuant à suivre du dedans au dehors les états simultanément juxtaposés dans ma conscience, et avant d’arriver jusqu’à l’horizon réel qui les enveloppait, je trouve des plaisirs d’un autre genre, celui d’être bien assis, de sentir la bonne odeur de l’air, de ne pas être dérangé par une visite[...]
Marcel Proust, Du côté de chez Swann, 1913


Ou bien qu'il y a une série d'objectifs possibles, et qu'on est arrivé jusqu'à celui-là.

Ohhhhhhh so it's like saying "we got there but only just"?

@temporary_user_name I wouldn't say "only just", I'd rather say "as far as" (implying we could have gone further but...)

The original English: The rain had finally stopped. I stood at the screen door and watched them step around the puddles on the walk as they made their way to the car. Your analysis of une certaine difficulté à atteindre la destination is exactly right, and the difficulty is conveyed in English by as they made their way ...

Je serai moins charitable que @jlliagre: le recours à jusqu'à est plutôt malvenu ici, il cherche à transmettre l'idée d'un parcours laborieux alors qu'arriver est relatif à l'extrême fin du parcours. Une expression juste serait p. ex. [...] pour progresser jusqu'à la voiture.
Je crois que stylistiquement, simplifier la citation était meilleur:  [...] je restai sur le seuil à les regarder contourner les flaques jusqu'à la voiture.

C'est une traduction d'un livre pour enfants anglais, donc je ne suis pas surpris si l'écriture n'est pas complètement fluide.

Marcel Proust (dans la réponse de @jlliagre) n'a pas cette excuse; pour le passage cité je crois que le traducteur cherche
à imiter le relâchement du français parlé. Il est très,très souvent possible d'éviter "arriver" + "jusqu'à"; l'idée que c'est plus soigné m'est personnelle.
